# E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache Error while using Picasso and okhttp in genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion, picasso, okhttp

I'm writing an app which loads a picture from a URL and display in an imageview.
here is the code...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Picasso picasso;
private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    String image_url ="http://www.empireonline.com/images/uploaded/wreck-it-ralph-box-office.jpg";



    okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this)
            .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient))
            .build();
    Context con = getApplicationContext();
    picasso.with(con)
            .load(image_url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .resize(60,60)
            .into(imageview);
}
```

The app doesn't crash but it does not show the picture either! in the LogCat i've got these 2 errors:

```
09-15 13:17:17.419    2358-2358/**************** E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
09-15 13:17:17.439    2358-2358/**************** E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
```

I'm using Genymotion 2.0.1 . Can u plz help me???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed the code by adding correct JAR Files! Please make sure that you have these libraries:

1- OKHTTP-2.0.0

2- OKHTTP-urlconnection-2.0.0 (not RC1 version!)

3- Okio-1.0.1

4- picasso-2.3.4

if you use these libraries, GradienCache Error will be handled as an exception and you'll no more get force close!

Comment: can u tell me these jar file  link

Comment: where place of this files exactly?

Comment: @peyman.H the libraries required all together or just anyone is enough, as i am not using picasso.

Comment: @Sunishtha Singh the first 2 are related to each other. But the last should are up to you

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by increasing the virtual machine's memory. Default setting in Genymotion is very small.

Open your **VirtualBox Manager** (NOT Genymotion). Select your desire Android VM and go to Settings / System and change the slider for Base Memory. You can also increase the Video Memory in the Display tab.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer! but it didn't help! :(

Answer (score 2):

Also try this

> Genymotion > Settings > Misc > Clear Cache

this works for me