# error Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache

Tags: android

I write application which parse data from one site and then shows it in ListView, Now my programm must parse 25 items of class ApartmentBase;

```
public class ApartmentBase extends BaseEntity implements IApartmentBase {
private String detailsLink;
private String district;
private Integer price;
private String address;

public String getAddress() {
    if(address==null)
        return "-";
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getDistrict() {
    if(district==null)
        return "-";
    return district;
}

public void setDistrict(String district) {
    this.district = district;
}

public String getDetailsLink() {
    return detailsLink;
}

public void setDetailsLink(String detailsLink) {
    this.detailsLink = detailsLink;
}

public Integer getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(Integer price) {
    this.price = price;
}
```

}

I use AsyncTask loader and custom adapter inherited from ArrayAdapter, but when I do loading I have crash with erorrs, 
E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
09-22 15:29:01.539  E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints() what to do with it?

Comment: [see this answer hopefully it will solve your issue][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849392/e-openglrenderer-getting-max-texture-size-from-gradiencache-error-while-using-p/25855508#25855508

Answer (score 0):

It was problem with GenyMotion,when I run it in new device all works is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> `Genymotion > Settings > Misc > Clear Cache`

this works for me

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by increasing the virtual machine's memory. Default setting in Genymotion is very small.

Open your **VirtualBox** Manager (NOT Genymotion). Select your desire Android VM and go to Settings / System and change the slider for Base Memory. You can also increase the Video Memory in the Display tab.
[E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache Error while using Picasso and okhttp in genymotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849392/e-openglrenderer-getting-max-texture-size-from-gradiencache-error-while-using-p)