# Android GenyMotion Error, Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, genymotion

---

Guys,

New to this forum, 
I am stuck here , I am using Genymotion emulator for android, when I am trying to Run my android application, nothing appears on emulator, but when I looked into LogCat I see this error

Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache

MAX_TEXTURESIZE: 8192

Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE Caches::Initconstraints()

MAX_TEXTURESIZE: 8192

Since I am new to this forum, I can not enclose the picture for your reference,

Thanks,

---

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849392/e-openglrenderer-getting-max-texture-size-from-gradiencache-error-while-using-p/26074146#26074146 refer this answer

Comment: @SunishthaSingh those are the network and image loading libraries but i am running the very basic application containing Two Activities and Fragments and a ListView, there is no images and no network request in my application but i am facing the SAME ERROR. But my app is running on API 19 very well but not on API 23 and further. So do you have any solution

Answer (score -1):

Open your VirtualBox Manager (NOT Genymotion). Select your desire Android VM and go to Settings / System and change the slider for Base Memory. You can also increase the Video Memory in the Display tab.

Comment: did that still remains the same

Comment: Changing video memory will do absolutely nothing.

Comment: @pcans i am running the very basic application containing Two Activities and Fragments and a ListView, there is no images and no network request in my application but i am facing the SAME ERROR. But my app is running on API 19 very well but not on API 23 and further. So do you have any solution